# Redirecting to other page when alert message clicked OK in an Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Iam newbie to Ionic and working on an Ionic app. I did showing alert message in the page when the user device location is OFF. this alert message is working fine. Now my requirement is to redirect the app to different page (home.page.html) when alert message clicked OK. I used return this.homePage but it is not working. I think i need to write some function to redirect this to home. Below is my code.

location.ts page:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.helperService.showLoader("Fetching your location");
this.mapElement = this.mapElement.nativeElement;
this.getUserLocation()
  .then((res) => {
    this.myLocation = res;
    this.helperService.hideLoader();
    return this.myLocation;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
      this.helperService.hideLoader();

      alert(
        "Location setting should be ON to use this feature, please turn it ON in the Location Settings on your phone "
      );

      return this.homePage;
  })
```

please help me how can i do this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of JavaScript alert you should use the Ionic alert. this will provide you callback for it

I have added sample code below please use this one. i have added two`ok and cancel`button in the sample code if you want one in them you can remove it from the array

**//Import statement**

```
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

**//Constructor**

```
constructor(private alertController : AlertController) {
    
}
```

add these two functions in you page class

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.helperService.showLoader("Fetching your location");
    this.mapElement = this.mapElement.nativeElement;
    this.getUserLocation()
      .then((res) => {
        this.myLocation = res;
        this.helperService.hideLoader();
        return this.myLocation;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
        this.helperService.hideLoader();

        this.presentAlertConfirm(
          "Location setting should be ON to use this feature, please turn it ON in the Location Settings on your phone "
        );

      })
  }

  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      header: 'application name',
      message: 'Location setting should be ON to use this feature, please turn it ON in the Location Settings on your phone',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Okay');
             //you can write your code or redirection 
             // sample redirection code 
             // this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Taylor Rahul, thank you for your answer. when i applied your code iam getting declarations errors. Iam newbie to this ionic iam not understanding what to do with those things. Can it possible to redirect to other page keeping this javascript alert only. Please help. thank you

Comment: can you please let me know what declarations error you are getting .. you can update your question. together we will sort it out .. JavaScript doesn't provide this callback so it will be problematic for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer and have added almost all declarations. please have a look now

Comment: @ Taylor Rahul, getting error cannot find name 'presentAlertConfirm'. also getting errors in other alerts added in the page. It would be great if continue discussion in chat i will share issue exactly.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add this before the function name. i have updated my code again. please use updated one. and let me know if you still have any error

Comment: No, getting error at alert message as Expected 0 arguments but got 1. Also other alert messages getting error as This Expression is not callable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226973/discussion-between-shaik-and-taylor-rahul).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NavController to navigate application to home page.

Ionic V3 : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/

Ionic V4+ : this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');

Use toaster controller instead of alert()

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast

```
async ngOnInit() {
 this.helperService.showLoader("Fetching your location");
 this.mapElement = this.mapElement.nativeElement;
 this.getUserLocation()
  .then((res) => {
    this.myLocation = res;
    this.helperService.hideLoader();
    return this.myLocation;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
    this.helperService.hideLoader();

     const toast = await this.toastController.create({
     message: 'Location setting should be ON to use this feature, please turn it ON in the Location Settings on your phone ',
     position: 'top',
     buttons: [
       {
         text: 'cancel',
         handler: () => {
           console.log('Cancel clicked');
         }
        }, {
         text: 'Done',
         role: 'cancel',
         handler: () => {
           this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
         }
       }
    ]
  });
  toast.present();
```

})

You can add buttons as per your requirement

Comment: hi @Hitesh Patel, Thank you so much for your answer. Idont know when i applied your code the location OFF functionality is not working neither it showing an alert. can it be possible to redirect with javascript alert only. Please help me. thanks